# Stop running VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a simple VBScript, which executes a batch file in the background. It starts correctly and it's working, but I can't stop it.

I already checked all of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017850/how-to-stop-a-vb-script-running-in-windows) answers, but I have no `cscript.exe` and no `wscript.exe` running

Any ideas?

Comment: Then what makes you think its running.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you wouldn't be showing a process for a process that is running. Perhaps check out [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) as it has much more info available to hunt down processes then the usual windows built in.

Comment: Hm, I found it with this process explorer. The processes isn't there, but the cmd.exe process what is started by the vbs is running. I killed that and it solved the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding an "exit" statement at the end of your batch as long as you don't need to visually see the results (you could just write them to a text file). Just saying, in case you're experiencing this problem in the future.